# R : remove NULL in each column while keeping order in the column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with NULLs or Nos in R:
Example:

```
people1 <- c("Variety 1", "Variety 2", "Variety 3", "Variety 4", "Variety 5")
people2 <- c("Variety 4", "Variety 3", "Variety 2", "Variety 1", "NULL")
people3 <- c("Variety 3", "Variety 2", "NULL", "Variety 4", "Variety 1")
df2 <- data.frame(people1, people2, people3)
```

For each column, if there is a NULL or NA, I want them removed and the next item moved up to replace.
So that the columns may end with NULLs but not have them in the middle.

Can you help?
Thanks!

Comment: What do your rows represent in this instance, if items can be moved around in this way?  It my be that there is a better overall way of showing this data.

Comment: So if you move up all items followin NA, what do you put in the last row, for example, in people3?

Comment: Also, are these `"NULL"` in string form, or actually `NULL`?

Comment: It is free listing, and the software I will analyse the data accepts csv where columns don't have the same length, but no NULL in the middle. So I want to convert my file to the proper format: NULL or NA at the end, and that I will then remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the question was changed after I answered it and the answer to the original question is at the bottom under Old.  The answer to the new question is:

```
replace(df2, TRUE, lapply(df2, function(x) c(x[x != "NULL"], x[x == "NULL"])))
```

giving:

```
    people1   people2   people3
1 Variety 1 Variety 4 Variety 3
2 Variety 2 Variety 3 Variety 2
3 Variety 3 Variety 2 Variety 4
4 Variety 4 Variety 1 Variety 1
5 Variety 5      NULL      NULL
```

### Old

Convert the "NULL" values to NA and use `na.locf` (last occurrence carried forward).  It will also work if there are multiple consecutive "NULL" values.

```
library(zoo)

m <- as.matrix(df2)
replace(df2, TRUE, na.locf(ifelse(m == "NULL", NA, m)))
```

giving:

```
    people1   people2   people3
1 Variety 1 Variety 4 Variety 3
2 Variety 2 Variety 3 Variety 2
3 Variety 3 Variety 2 Variety 2
4 Variety 4 Variety 1 Variety 4
5 Variety 5 Variety 1 Variety 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I was probably not clear. If there is NULLs it is fine, it is just that I want them at the end of the column, and the rest of the column remains in the same order.
Like if col 3 is var1, var2, NULL, var4, var3 then it should become var1, var2, var4, var3 , NULL

Answer (score -1):

```
df3 <- data.frame(
  people1 = c(people1[people1 != "NULL"], people1[people1=="NULL"]),
  people2 = c(people2[people2 != "NULL"], people2[people2=="NULL"]),
  people3 = c(people3[people3 != "NULL"], people3[people3=="NULL"])
        )
```

Will work for "NULL" strings.

```
> df3
    people1   people2   people3
1 Variety 1 Variety 4 Variety 3
2 Variety 2 Variety 3 Variety 2
3 Variety 3 Variety 2 Variety 4
4 Variety 4 Variety 1 Variety 1
5 Variety 5      NULL      NULL
```

Comment: Thank you but not convenient for many columns ;-)

Comment: True, G. Grothendieck's solution is more generalised for any size dataset.